# When travelling to China, does the Hijab have to be removed?

Tags: china, officials, islam

As most of the people know, the Hijab is a headscarf which Muslim women are ordered to wear in Islam. Hearing the recent news, it appears China has banned the Hijab and other types of Islamic clothing. Do I need to remove the Hijab in Beijing, as I have a flight there and a hotel stay for one day. Since I am a traveller, do these laws count?

Comment: The ban on <font color="#3300CC"><a href="https://www.uniquehijabs.com" rel="nofollow noreferrer">hijabs</a> is only on uyghurs living in the uyghur autonamous region. If you are visitor the ban does not apply to you. I have seen many muslim women in China wearing the hijab last year.

Answer (score 8):

This is an impossible question to answer definitely as it depends on multiple factors. It looks like the [ban is mostly centered in the Uighur parts of western China](https://www.express.co.uk/news/world/786624/china-veil-beard-ban-xinjiang-muslim-uighur-religious-extremism/amp) and the ban itself is mostly concerned with covering the face with a veil or full beard.

So you may be ok in Beijing but what might be ok in Beijing’s international airport or at a large hotel might be more problematic if you’re on Tiananmen Square where they are very sensitive to Uighur protests or at the bus or train stations where there have been terrorist attacks.

Certainly, if you cover but don’t veil, the standard hijab can be worn in a way that doesn’t differ significantly from how modest women dress in China. You have long sleeves, long pants, and cover your hair with a head scarf. Many non-Muslim women dress similarly and so you can pass in more cosmopolitan areas. I’d still carry a passport in case you get stopped by public security.

You will, however, encounter more resistance in more places if you wear the niqab or cover the face as that is very different and will stand out, as well as make public security nervous because they can’t see your face.

Answer (score 8):

I've traveled through Beijing Capital Airport multiple times wearing hijab without major problems.  I have not been required to remove my headscarf.  Sometimes they scan it (with the wand) somewhat carefully, but that's about it.

(In fact, while I don't cover currently, I covered for nearly two years while living in China.  I didn't find it a problem.)

> Hearing the recent news, it appears China has banned the Hijab and other types of Islamic clothing.

This is not the case throughout China, and it's certainly not the case in Beijing.  I believe it only applies in Xinjiang province, and only to Chinese nationals.

People in China are generally free to wear hijab (although it's not very popular), and if you go to a halal restaurant (usually 兰州拉面 [Lánzhōu lāmiàn] is halal), usually the cooks are women who wear headscarves.  Many female outdoor workers wear something comparable to hijab to protect themselves from the sun.

Other comments:

- Some explosives tests might involve men who may attempt to swab you with a piece of paper.
- As far as I'm aware, there's no prayer rooms at Beijing Capital Airport.  I find a quiet corner and pray on a mat there.
- While China has [freedom of religion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_religion_in_China), China generally disallows "preaching".